# How to override the model field in django form

Tags: python, django

In my Model i have this

```
description = tinymce_models.HTMLField(help_text='A short descripton')
```

Now i want to render this field as normal text area not the tinymece field. I can't edit the models file.

Is there any way i can override the same field in my form.

like this

```
description = forms.widgets.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':40})
```

I tried this but didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify what widget you want to use in `modelform`s `Meta` class. For example:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 40}),
        }
```

Reference : [Overriding the default field types or widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets)